# GUAVA CACHE - Calculate weights dynamically

Tags: java, guava

## Problem

I'm trying to cache a set and I need to remove the entry if the set is empty to save memory. Guava Cache computes the weights when the entry is created instead of computing it on every write/read. Is there any workaround or another library that I can use to achieve this?
Thanks for helping.

## Cache instantiation

```
    Cache<String, Set<String>> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .maximumWeight(1)
            .weigher((Weigher<String, Set<String>>) (k, v) -> v.size() == 0 ? 1 : 0)
            .build();
```

Comment: Are you changing the size of the ```Set``` while it is stored in the cache? If so, I think it would need to be the responsibility of the code modifying the Set to remove it, not the cache or collection. If you tried to do it in the collection, you would have to loop through all entries to see which can be removed.

Comment: Yes, the set is changing. The problem is that I have to deal with all the concurrency. If that would work out of the box it would be great.

Comment: If you are modifying sets concurrently and assuming they are stored in a central repo, but then removing them from the repo via some sideline process, I believe you have an error-prone design. What if the eviction process kicks in at the same time another thread is adding to the set. I believe you need to put blocking around the use of each set and in the blocking thread add or remove from the shared collection.

Comment: An empty `Set` is extremely cheap. It's more expensive memory/cpu trying to cache it. You might instead consider a synchronized `SetMultimap`. You can achieve your goal if you use a `asMap().compute` function when writing to the set.

Comment: I'm don't want to save memory or anything like that. I'm interested in the eviction based on time.